# Weird output when i echo &note in PHP, how to fix it?

Tags: php, html

When I echo "&note" in PHP it becomes ¬e

```
<?
echo "&note";
?>
```

outputs:

```
¬e
```

I need the output to be:

```
&note
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: `&amp;note`, this is not a PHP issue, but an encoding one

Comment: that is not php, its the browser..
`php > echo "&node";` => `&node`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `&amp;` to echo an ampersand, `&not;` is html encoding for the mathematical not (¬) symbol.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is not by php it is because of browsers as it is encoding '&note' to its equivalent symbol.

try using

`echo "&amp;note";`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fix the issue you should `echo htmlspecialchars('&note');`

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize your input for HTML special characters in your php file using `htmlspecialchars`or `htmlentities`

```
echo htmlspecialchars('&note'); //OR 
echo htmlentities('&note');
```